# I want to return to first dialog everytime I press the cancel option

Tags: java, if-statement, joptionpane

I would like to return to my first dialog 'myPanel' everytime i press the cancel button. I managed to do this but it only works one time. have a look. I will appreciate your help. thanks in advance

```
int IPLBW = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel, "IPL BW 
UTILIZATION", 
JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
 nt laten = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel2, "IPL BW LATENCYN", 
 JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);


   if (IPLBW == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION && laten ==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION ) 
{  
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel, "IPL BW UTILIZATION", 
JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
               }      
  /*PRINTS SOMETHING FROM THE VALUE OF MYPANEL AND MYPANEL2*/

  else if (laten == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
       JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel, "IPL BW UTILIZATION", 
 JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
       JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel2, "IPL BW LATENCY", 
 JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
               }
```

Comment: Please take a minute and fix the messy indenting of your source code. It is way harder to read than it ought be.

Comment: put your code in a loop, that only breaks when you don't want to return

Comment: In short, put the conditions to stay inside a loop. I can´t give more advice/answer, because you didn't mention the rules to success or displaying again the dialogs.